# Is there a way to see who will win the election for Holy Roman Emperor in EU4?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In my current EU4 game, I'm in a tight race with Savoy for the title of Holy Roman Emperor. It basically comes down to the way The Palatinate breaks the tie, however, both of us are so low on its list that I can't see who they would rather chose. Is there any button or object that I can however over/click on that will tell me who would win the election if it were held today? This would be useful in general, not just for this game, as a way to double check what I found by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Palatinate choose neither of you their vote simply goes to the country they favor, leaving you in a tie. As far as I know the tie breaker is done as follows:

1. If one of the countries in the tie is the current Emperor they retain the title
2. If neither of the countries in the tie is the current Emperor the country with the highest prestige gets the title

So the way to check is to simply count the number of votes and compare yourself to Savoy on those 2 parameters.

Comment: If both have the same prestige, the lexicographically-precedent tag gets it.